# How check Flutter App on Apple Phone from IntelliJ on windows

Tags: ios, flutter, intellij-idea

I'm a bit confused because I made a flutter app with intelliJ under windows. The app works great on android phones. I now want to deploy it on Apple phones but I don't know how. I don't have an Apple computer. How should I do to deploy on Apple phones and possibly make the necessary adaptations?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible at this point in time.

For deploying an app to App Store/Testflight you would need a macOS device. If you're out of luck for that, you can try some cloud solutions that run macOS and let you build your apps in the cloud and deploy it to Testflight/App Store. I have used cloud solutions for months and was very happy with them.